# ZTE Z820 Can't bypass Google Account after Factory Reset

Tags: google-account

ZTE Z820 Phone purchased in U.S. during 3 month stay. I've factory reset to unluck and for use in Ireland, but now can't bypass the Google Account. Stuck in the loop for user name and password. I have the correct account and password details, but won't recognize the password. It is the correct password, I've confirmed it.
I've viewed and tried various methods online, but none are z820 specific.
Can anyone help. Please?

Answer (score 1):

Check if your 2 way authentication is ON for your google account.

If it is ON, you need to generate a password for your new android device. You can find this option in your account setting -> security.

Use new generated password for login, it should work....

Comment: thanks sir but the 2 way is not on. fyi i'm getting to browse via the open source search method and was able to see that two way is off. i attempted to turn on and create new password via the zte z820 phone device but via the open source method of access javascript not enabled.